# Pyside6 - How do I add a stylesheet to a toolbar button when using QAction?

Tags: python, user-interface, tooltip, pyside

How do I change the color of the tooltip message? The stylesheet is not recognized. This Python class draws a toolbar and adds itself to the parent window

```
 def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.toolbar = QToolBar("toolbar")
    self.toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))
    connect_action = QAction(QIcon('icon:icons8_connect_50.png'), "&Connect", self.parent)
    connect_action.setCheckable(True)
    connect_action.triggered.connect(self.connect_button)
    self.toolbar.addAction(connect_action)
    connect_action.setToolTip('Connect')

    connect_action.setStyleSheet("QToolTip {color:rgb(0, 0, 0);"
                               " background-color: rgb(255, 255, 204);"
                               " border: 2px solid black;"
                               " font-family: Times New Roman;}")
```

I created a toolbar with multiple QAction items, each with an associated icon. Since QAction is not a widget, I couldn't apply a stylesheet to the button. How can I add a stylesheet when the item is not a widget but a QAction?

Updated

Comment: For future reference, please ensure that you provide a valid example (indentation included) and a *detailed* description of the problem. I *assume* that you want to set a stylesheet for **one specific** action added to a QToolBar, but the question (including its title) is a bit ambiguous, considering that actions can be added to very different widgets. This will help us to answer you more appropriately (so, it helps you too), and also others to find solutions for problems similar to yours.

Comment: I created a toolbar with multiple QAction items, each with an associated icon. Since QAction is not a widget, I couldn't apply a stylesheet to the button. I didn't know widgetForAction() . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stylesheets can only be applied to widgets, and QActions are **not** widgets: they are abstract objects that *may eventually* be shown on widgets that are able to display actions, but that can happen in very different ways.

For instance, an item in a QMenu, an icon in QLineEdit, or a button in QToolBar. In reality, actions can be used even if they are never shown.

This means that the possibility of using style sheets that are able to *target* actions (and especially *specific* actions) completely depends on the widget that displays them.
For example, QMenu only allows to change the appearance of *all* its actions, not specific ones.

Luckily, when an action is added to a QToolBar, it automatically creates a QToolButton for it (except when using a QWidgetAction that returns a different widget type).

QToolBar provides the possibility to retrieve the widget related to its actions by using [`widgetForAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtoolbar.html#widgetForAction), meaning that we can set individual stylesheets for each button:

```py
    self.toolbar.addAction(connect_action)
    toolButton = self.toolbar.widgetForAction(connect_action)
    toolButton.setStyleSheet('...')
```